# Get 'No rule to make target 'modules'. ' on make file

Tags: linux, drivers, script

While I am installing the driver of Realtek RTL8192EU chipset (0bda:818b) form this  [package](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_PyshAvItmPX3pwVEhKNEdDRTA/view?usp=sharing) and, follow the how-to-install.txt , I got error while running `sudo ./install.sh`

```
[tjm@ArchPad install_folder]$ LANG=en_US-utf8 sudo ./install.sh 
##################################################
Realtek Wi-Fi driver Auto installation script
Novembor, 21 2011 v1.1.0
##################################################
Decompress the driver source tar ball:

rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524
Authentication requested [root] for make clean:
cd hal/OUTSRC/ ; rm -fr */*.mod.c */*.mod */*.o */.*.cmd */*.ko
cd hal/OUTSRC/ ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd hal/led ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr */*/*.mod.c */*/*.mod */*/*.o */*/.*.cmd */*/*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr */*.mod.c */*.mod */*.o */.*.cmd */*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core/efuse ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep/linux ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
rm -fr Module.symvers ; rm -fr Module.markers ; rm -fr modules.order
rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko *~
rm -fr .tmp_versions
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.4.5-1-ARCH/build M=/tmp/install_folder/driver/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.2.2_7585.20130524  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/lib/modules/4.4.5-1-ARCH/build'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'modules'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/lib/modules/4.4.5-1-ARCH/build'  
Makefile:1043: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
```

And after I have installed `linux-headers` I have received new [errors](http://fpaste.org/354594/)

What can I do?

Edit this script or find a new driver to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the `linux-headers` package:

[image]

(There's not enough space to install `gcc` in the live environment. See the change of error after installing `linux-header`.)

P.S. Btw there are quite a few more maintained forks on github. For example: https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver

Comment: Thanks for your helping, but after I installing `linux-headers` some new [errors](http://fpaste.org/354594/) occured.

Comment: @TJM http://askubuntu.com/questions/593566/how-to-disable-werror-date-time-macro-date-might-prevent-reproducible-bui https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/commit/2b7b0110c60819c2d2865615d0819b88d58ccc1d